# jquery tablesorter farsi/persian issue on sorting tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

I using http://tablesorter.com/ script to order my tables 
when i order by "name" column that is written in persian language some characters not sorted correctly for example گ چ پ ژ 
this characters is not in arabic language but the other characters work perfectly

Please help me 
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In new versions (v2.12+) of [tableSorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/index.html) there is a function called "textSorter" that could solve this problm. But it must be used with [sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/) library. The code is something like this:

```
Array.AlphanumericSortOrder = "ا ب پ ت ث ج چ ح خ د ذ ر ز ژ ص ض ط ظ ع غ ف ق ک گ ل م ن و ه ی";
$("#simpleTable").tablesorter({
textSorter : {
0 : Array.AlphanumericSort,
}
});
```

Number 0 is the index of column (that means first column)